# How to setup OpenGL1.4 environment in Firemonkey App?

Tags: delphi, opengl, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

In older days I would create a TForm, place a TMyPanel on it (with overriden WM_PAINT message) and pass its Handle to a bunch of WGL functions that find a compatible pixelformat and create rendering context. Just like NeHe tutorials did it.

Now there comes FireMonkey application. How to get OpenGL 1.4 rendering context there that is working on Win and iOS?

**EDIT:** Been trying to make it to work by passing TForm.Handle (which is NativeUInt). Good news - no errors from OpenGL end, but bad news - no output on TForm either.. I'm obviously missing some critical piece here, does anyone has a working OpenGL in FireMonkey application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigations I have managed to create OpenGL context in FireMonkey on Windows platform. I don't have access to iOS yet, but I'm sure something can be done there as well.

To the solution: add `FMX.Platform.Win` to `uses` clause (might need to wrap it into `IFDEF`'s for iOS). Now we can use `FmxHandleToHWND(Form1.Handle)` to get valid `HWND`. Thats it. On MacOS the same is done by adding `FMX.Platform.Win` and through `H_WND := FmxHandleToObjC(AHandle);` call.

Answer (score 2):

Firemonkey provides an abstraction layer.

So on Windows your using DirectX and on OSX and iOS your using OpenGL/Quartz.
On windows it's also possible for things to fall back to GDI+

Given this one must take into account that the rendering destination may not always be OpenGL, and it may not always be the same even on the same platform.

`TCanvas` in part of this abstraction layer.

There are 3 current implementations of `TCanvas`, your application may be using any of these.

- `FMX.Canvas.D2D.pas` - Direct2d
- `FMX.Canvas.GDIP.pas` - GDI+
- `FMX.Canvas.Mac.pas` - Mac

The platform implementation details are typically hidden in private sections are are not accessible.

You also have `TPlatform` in `FMX.Platform.pas` which hides the implementation details and publishes a single API (limited in scope) that is designed to work on all platforms.

If you use `FMX.Platform.Win.pas` you can get the windows handle for a given `TFmxHandle`

If you use `FMX.Platform.Mac.pas` you can get the `IObjectiveC` for a given `TFmxHandle`

However on IOS there is no equivalent function in `FMX_Platform_iOS.pas`

Comment: Your answer is good, but it didn't allowed me to achieve my goal just yet. Seems like something is wrong with that TfmxHandle.